# Using NAS Server as a Database Server, a good option?

Tags: mysql, database, network-attached-storage

Introdution: I have six dedicaded servers with localhost dababases, additional I have rented a NAS server (NFS HA Hybrid) mounted in each dedicaded server under /mnt directory, I want to use this as a DB server.

Objective: Now the databases are localhost, I want (for example) that the dedicated server 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 can access to the dedicated 1 databases. Additionally there are many process in each dedicaded server accessing to a single database.

I have read that I can change the mysql database directory to the /mnt directory, that could be a good option?

Answer (score 0):

If you value performance and non-corrupted data, databases should always use direct-attached (or other block-based) storage.

Answer (score 0):

NFS (and other network shared, file-level storage) typically does not work very well with databases. However, it is not always the case. [Here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=1211229) you can find an interesting (albeit short) thread on the argument.

The bottom line is that for safety, easy configuration and administration you use direct attached storage (DAS). If you can/are able to fine tune NFS configuration, it should not be a big problem using it for a database, unless specifically noted. However, a single wrong mount option and you will face very serious corruption issues.